# $y=S y'$ implies $d^n y=|\text{det }S|d^n y'$?

Tags: linear-algebra

An assertion is implicitly stated in a book without explanation:

Given that:

- $S$ is an orthogonal matrix constructed by using the normalised eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix as its columns.
- $S$ transforms a set of variables $y=(y_1\cdots y_n)^T$ to another set of variables $y'=(y_1'\cdots y_n')^T$ via $y'=S^T y$ (or equivalently, $y=Sy'$).

The author asserts that:
$$d^n y=|\text{det }S|d^n y'$$

I wonder why it is true. Note that the author mentioned Jacobian in the previous section:

$$dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_n=|J|dy_1dy_2\cdots dy_n$$

But I can't think of any relationship between them.

Could anyone explain why this assertion is true? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your map $S$ is linear so the matrix $S$ is the same as the Jacobian matrix, whose determinant is often denoted as simply $J$. Also note that $\det S=\det S^T$.

Let me rewrite the coordinate transformation as $y=Ax$. How does it affect the volume form? There is a formula for a pull-back of the differential forms where $J$ indeed appears, see a textbook on differential geometry, for example Frankel's "The Geometry of Physics".

If you want an explanation within linear algebra, consider what happens to the (infinitesimal) parallelepiped formed by the (tangent) vectors $v_1\wedge...v_n$. The new parallelepiped is $Av_1\wedge...Av_n$. The determinant of the matrix made of the vectors as its columns $(Av_1|...Av_n) = AV$ has the geometric meaning of the volume of the parallelepiped. Using the property $\det AV=\det A\cdot\det V$ we see that the (unsigned) volume gets multiplied by $|\det A|$.

For an orthogonal matrix $|\det S|=1$, and the volume (form) does not change (in absolute value).